# Going from a List View to a Web View

Tags: android, url, listview, webview

I'm trying to figure out how to get from a List View to a Web View.

I have a list of different items, and depending on which item is selected I want to load a different URL for the Web View.

I cannot figure out how to do it in the same class because I cannot extend Activity and ListActivity.

I have tried making a switch statement depending on which list item was selected, and then assigning the URL and loading it in a different class, but that seems a little too complicated.

Is there an easier way to do this??

Comment: did you tried to create a .xml with as webviews as your options in the list view?and then call in a seperate class every webview you like within an onClick method?

Answer (score 2):

I think you did the right thing:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    change(position);
}
void change(int position){
    Uri uri;
    switch(position){
       case 1:
          uri=Uri.parse(yourTextContaingUrl1);
       case 2:
          uri=Uri.parse(yourTextContaingUrl2);
       case 3:
          uri=Uri.parse(yourTextContaingUrl3);
    }
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot figure out how to do it in
>   the same class because I cannot extend
>   Activity and ListActivity.

ListActivity extends Activity...

Comment: I should have known that... Haha.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will call WebView for given URL

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(yourTextContaingUrl);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
activity.startActivity(intent);
return true;
```

Comment: Is the ACTION_VIEW Intent the same as a webview?  Any way to get rid of the browser bar up top?

Comment: Intent concept is a bit tricky to understand. One need to supply Intent with specific data (uri and data type) then system should find (if possible) appropriate application/activity which will handle request. So from your side you just need to prepare appropriate query to system (which is in code above). For sure it may happen that system will not use WebView to display your url, but smth else (depending on what installed in particular phone)